# How to redirect all pages to same page on a subdomain using htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, forwarding

I'm new to htaccess but i would like to do this

For example, I want to forward:

```
www.abc.com/page_1.html 
www.abc.com/folder123/page_a.html  
www.abc.com/folder123/page_b.html
```

to:

```
subdomain.abc.com/page_1
subdomain.abc.com/folder123/page_a     
subdomain.abc.com/folder123/page_b
```

Note: abc.com (HTML) and subdomain.abc.com (on Wordpress) is on different web servers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^abc\.com$ [OR]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.abc\.com$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/\.well-known/pki-validation/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$

RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/www\.subdomain.abc\.com\/" [R=301,L]
```